# Warning: ftp_put() expects parameter 3 to be a valid path, string given

Tags: php

I'm attempting to get a file from a URL and then upload that file via FTP to another server with PHP. I'm receiving the error **Warning: ftp_put() expects parameter 3 to be a valid path, string given**

```
// file to move:
$local_file = file_get_contents("http://cdn.server.com/affiliate/1.jpg");
$ftp_path = "/virtualhosts/path/for/upload/1.jpg";

// connect to FTP server (port 21)
$conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die ("Cannot connect to host");

// send access parameters
$ftp_login = ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login");

// turn on passive mode transfers (some servers need this)
//ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// perform file upload
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_BINARY);

var_dump($upload);
exit();
```

The var_dump() of $upload is NULL. The URL is correct (obviously not in this example) as I can var_dump the $local_file and see the contents.

How do I convert the string returned in file_get_contents() to a resource that can be used with the ftp_put() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nospor and the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) say, you need to provide a **valid path** not the contents of the file.
It seems that `http://cdn.server.com/affiliate/1.jpg` isn't located on your server, based on that, you can use [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) to download the remote file and then upload it to the remote server, something like:

```
<?php

$remoteFile = "http://cdn.server.com/affiliate/1.jpg";
// get the filename of the remote file(1.jpg)
$localFile = basename($remoteFile).PHP_EOL;
// copy the remote file to /tmp/1.jpg
copy($remoteFile, "/tmp/".$localFile);
$ftp_path = "/virtualhosts/path/for/upload/$localFile";
// connect to FTP server (port 21)
$conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die ("Cannot connect to host");
// send access parameters
$ftp_login = ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login");
// perform file upload
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, "/tmp/".$localFile, FTP_BINARY);
// delete the temporary file
unlink("/tmp/".$localFile);
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read examples from manual

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

3rd parameter must be just path to a file not a result of file_get_contents()

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution, partially thanks to the comment of @nospor about the 3rd parameter needing to be a local path and not the file itself. Yes, the manual says this but is clearly the portion I was overlooking.

Here's the bit that takes the result of file_get_contents() and saves it to a local directory which can then be used with ftp_put():

```
// save the file locally so it can be used for FTP
$local_file_path = '/var/www/temp_images/' . $new_image;
file_put_contents($local_file_path, $remote_file_contents);
```